# How can I print a variable with text in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to print a text with the name too.

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
name = fake.name()

print(name)
```

but i want it to print some plain text as well in that print.

like Hello, my name is: < Fake Name Generated Above >

Answer (score 2):

Fancier, do:

`print(f'Hello my name is {name}.')`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do that

```py
# f-strings
print(f"Hello, my name is: {name}")

# Str.format()
print("Hello, my name is: {name}".format(name))

# Concatenation
print("Hello, my name is: " + name)

# Simple print
print("Hello, my name is: ", name)
```

You can choose whichever one you prefer the most.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
print("Hello, my name is:", name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try directly printing the string and variable (comma separated) or use the string format()

```py
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
name = fake.name()

print("Hello, my name is:",name)

#or
your_text="Hello my name is: "
print("{your_text} {name}".format(yourtext, name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare a new variable in which you concatenate the text and the name. Then you can print that. This might be useful if you are using this text multiple times.

For example:

```
name = fake.name()
text = "Hello, my name is: " + name
```

this would only work if the name is a string. if it is not you would have to add the str() function.

For example:

```
name = fake.name()
text = "Hello, my name is: " + str(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Powershell was tagged but, heres how you do it in Posh:

```
#Keeping the string an object
Write-Output "Hello World"
#or:
"Hello World"

#Printing to screen
Write-Host "Hello world"

#With Color
Write-Host "Hello World" -ForeGroundColor Red

#in a variable
$String = "Hello World"

#To print the variable
$String
```